# ¿ Cómo puedo pasarle el nombre de la tabla a la que quiero hacer la consulta en Node Js?

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Esta es mi consulta:

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM ? WHERE `id_users` = 17 AND `date` = CURRENT_DATE() AND `departureTime` > 13', table, (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  res.status(200).json(results);
});
```

El problema que detecta es error en la sintaxis de SQL. Porque pasa el nombre de la siguiente manera: 'nombre_tabla' con las comillas, y ese es el error. Pero no se como pasarle el nombre sin las comillas.

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería.

El error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''chanaral' WHERE `id_users` = '17' AND `date` = CURRENT_DATE() AND `departureTim' at line 1.
```

Comment: Coloca los parámetros (en este caso `table`) como un array: `db.query(query, [params], callback);` aunque no creo que impacte mucho. De cualquier modo, podrías proporcionar el query que se genera y llega a MySQL y el error que te da (el stack completo de ser posible). Adicionalmente te invito a realizar el [tour], para ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: También probe colocandolo en un array pero sigue pasando el nombre con las comillas. he buscado por todos lados y siempre cuando hacen una query le pasan el nombre hardcodedeado y no me estaria sirviendo.

Comment: Entonces proporciona el query que llega y el stack del error por favor. Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta en cualquier momento para agregar más detalles a tu pregunta.

Comment: si ahi edite la pregunta, disculpame soy nuevo en Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás utilizando `?` cuando deberías utilizar `??`.

- `??` es para identidicadores
- `?` es para valores

Los nombres de las tablas, los nombres de campos son identificadores. En la [documentación](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers) puedes encontrar más ejemplos de lo que te menciono.

Con lo anterior aclarado, tu código debería quedar así:

```javascript
db.query('SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE id_users = 17 AND date = CURRENT_DATE() AND departureTime > 13', table, (error, results) => {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    res.status(200).json(results);
});
```

Comment: Esa era la solución, Muchísimas gracias !!